# xcode 6.0 beta version development and apple approval

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing application with xcode 6.0 for beta version of iOS 8.0. Would apple approve the application developed for iOS 8.0 beta version ?

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to wait until the final iOS 8 and Xcode 6 are ready. It's probably only a month or so.